# Android Gradle error : Invalid argument

Tags: android, build.gradle

I don't arrive to understand why I have this error.
F.I : I use Gradle 2.14.1 with plugin 2.1.3.

This is the error message :

```
 WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for []
```

Somebody can help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to Internet.
Go to Preferences > Gradle and uncheck "Offline work" and sync again.
Android studio will download the missing file.

Comment: I have unchecked "Offline work" but the error persists

Comment: Well ... Download latest version of gradle from [here](https://gradle.org/gradle-download/). Go to gradle-wrapper properties and replace the link by the path to your downloaded gradle file. It worked for me manytimes.

Comment: I added the zip in my wrapper folder and I replaced url like this :

Comment: distributionUrl=./gradle-3.2.1-all.zip
Is this correct ?

Comment: yes ... sync with it ... if it fails then try with complete path.

Comment: Is it necessary to configure proxy because I have an error : Unknown host 'gradle'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

Comment: Go to..

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings

and press checkConnection button for test

Comment: The error persists even after the configuration, maybe I forgot something !

Comment: If I resume the steps : 1. change distribution url with distributionUrl=file\://gradle/wrapper/gradle-2.1.3-all.zip                                                   2. I enable proxy                                                                                                       3. I enable offline work                                                                                                        Is it correct for you ?

Comment: sequence doesnt matter

Comment: I learned that the project was en Eclipse project...   The importation was not tested

Comment: Android studio take care of every thing while importing Eclipse project. You should use **Import**  to import project.